# iis 6 native compression not working on ssl

Tags: iis, https, compression

i have a problem where my ASP.NET web application files (.js, .css, .aspx) doesn't get compress when i access it from https. However the files get compressed when i accessed it from http. Any idea what causing this problem?. It over a week and i cannot find any solution from the net. I have ask my network administrator to check proxy settings but they said all ok. My last resort to reinstall IIS but i need to know if you guys have any better solution.